# discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler results blank

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

Having trouble with CloudKit's discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler not returning anything in the discoveredUserInfo array. I have a test app on two phones. One person can see the other (discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler returns the 2nd user's info via lookup) but not vice-versa. I checked all the settings on both phones, including iCloud Drive->Look Me Up By Email, the correct email addresses in the contacts list, iCloud drive is turned on for the app. Everything.

I noticed that even on the phone that can see the 2nd user, sometimes the discoveredUserInfo array is blank and sometimes it returns the 2nd user, seemingly at random.

Anyone else seeing this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple only allows e certain amount of requests per period. You would then expect a CKError. I created a bug report with apple for this (ID = 19712839)
I would suggest that you do the same.

Comment: Hmm. Never get an error in the error parameter, just an empty array. I figured the intermittent blanks was some kind of optimization, but the one phone that never gets any is annoying.

Comment: My bug report today got this status: Duplicate of 20143672 (Open)